# Why is this application throwing OpenGL errors when run in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, wine, opengl

I have an application that ran flawlessly in Wine 1.3 in Maverick. However, when run in Natty under Unity, I get the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  27 (X_GLXCreatePbuffer)
  Serial number of failed request:  1703
  Current serial number in output stream:  1704
```

...and then Unity crashes. Is there anything I can do to make this application work?

Comment: Does this issue occur when you run the Wine application in Ubuntu Classic - make sure that no Compiz Visual effects are enabled i.e. set to None not Normal/Extra

Comment: @foss: I haven't tried that.

Comment: Still experiencing this problem @GeorgeEdison?

Comment: The GLX opcode hints that you have an Intel graphics adapter. So, I think you do not have PBuffer support. You can check this by running glxinfo - the `glx server version string` should return >= 1.3 for pbuffers to be supported. 
There is a support thread around this issue here: http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/intel-gfx/2009-July/003381.html
You could try forcing software rendering: `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1`
Let me know if this helps and I'll make an answer.

Comment: This cannot be solved unless you tell us what is the application you are trying to run. Also can you please tell us if changing from Unity to Unity2D makes a difference?